# Checking status of Task Queue in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, queue, task, task-queue

I'm putting several tasks into a task queue and would like to know when the specific tasks are done. I haven't found anything in the API about call backs, or checking the status of a task, so I thought I'd see what other people do, or if there's a work around (or official) way to check. I don't care about individual tasks, if it helps, I'm putting 6 different tasks in, and want to know when all 6 are complete.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new REST/JSON task queue API will let you do this.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/rest.html

This does not scale well to thousands of tasks...

I do like the pipeline API suggestion though!

Comment: Can you explain how the new task queue API accomplishes this? You can GET a task, but it doesn't seem to include any sort of status or indication of success or failure.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to accomplish this with the pipeline api. You make something dependent on all 6 tasks and let it rip.

http://code.google.com/p/appengine-pipeline/

Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can use memcache.  Use a unique key specific to this task group.  Set a count when you kick off your tasks, and have each task atomically decrement it.  When the value is 0, your tasks are complete.  The task that finds this value to be 0 can call your callback.

Comment: What about the possibility that the memcache can go away since its not guaranteed to stay? Just backing it up in a datastore is not enough because of race conditions during save. How does one deal with that?

Comment: I think you can deal with the race conditions when saving to the data store by using a transaction.